# Azure managed cassandra cluster public IP

Tags: java, database, azure, cassandra

I am creating Azure managed Cassandra cluster following the documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/managed-instance-apache-cassandra/create-cluster-portal

It creates all 3 nodes successfully and assigns private IP. But to connect via java program requires public IP to connect with any contact point.

Documentation also says.

> Azure Managed Instance for Apache Cassandra does not create nodes with
> public IP addresses, so to connect to your newly created Cassandra
> cluster, you will need to create another resource inside the VNet.
> This could be an application, or a Virtual Machine with Apache's
> open-source query tool CQLSH installed. You can use a template to
> deploy an Ubuntu Virtual Machine. When deployed, use SSH to connect to
> the machine, and install CQLSH using the below commands

I am running a Java program in a different VM, how to establish the connection between Java Instance VM to Cassandra Cluster. What will be IP to communicate

[image]

Comment: This SO thread may help you-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53571213/cannot-connect-cassandra-client-on-public-ip

Comment: You can refer to [Unable to connect to cassandra hosted on my VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32376091/unable-to-connect-to-cassandra-hosted-on-my-vm)

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced the same issue and unable to connect from my local machine to Azure Managed Cassandra, based on my research these are the ways to connect to Azure Managed Cassandra

1- Try with VM which is present in the same Virtual network as of Azure Managed Cassandra.

2- Try to perform V Net peering for the the Virtual network of the VM in which you wanted to connect to Azure Managed Cassandra with the Virtual network of Azure managed Cassandra

Comment: as Cassandra runs in a VNet, running VMs in the same Vnet or peered VNet can solve the connectivity issues,
if you have to connect to Managed Cassandra from your Computer you can also use Azure Point-to-Site VPN (
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-about) this way you will create a VPN connection to your azure VNET